# Approval Process in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, automation, approval-process

I have a process builder in place to submit a record for approval automatically, but when the record is edited and I try to save the record I get a trigger error "This record is currently in an approval process. A record can be in only one approval process at a time." I have Record Editability  set to Administrator OR Current Approver. I'm guessing from the error message it's trying to submit the record into an approval process when it is currently in one. I have no problem editing the record when it is not automatically submitted. Can anybody think of how to achieve submitting the record automatically through process builder? Is there additional logic I need or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a checkbox field on the object you're working with, which would serve as a flag to prevent recursion and the approval process from firing again.  You should be able to do something like this:

- Create a new checkbox field (let's call it Approval Flag)
- In the approval process, add a step upon submission to check the Approval Flag field to TRUE
- Update your process builder criteria to look at the Approval Flag field.  Add the logic of Approval Flag = FALSE in addition to your other logic to kick off the flow.

This should help prevent the misfiring.